# Pull out measurable function out of a stochastic integral

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I am trying to solve the following problem III.2.30 from Karatzas, Shreve book: assume that $M$ is a continuos local martingale and $X$ is a "proper" integrand, i.e. a measurable, adapted process, such that $\int_0^T X_t^2dt$ is almost surely finite for every $T$. Then for every $\mathcal{F}_s$-measurable random variable $Z$ we have 
$$
\int_s^t ZX_udM_u=Z\int_s^t X_udM_u 
$$
Obviously, first I tried to prove in case when $M$ is a continuous, square integrable martingale (for simplicity I assume further that $M$ is a Brownian motion $W$) and integrand $X$ belongs to more narrow class of measurable, adapted processes such that $[X]_T\triangleq \mathbb{E}\int_0^TX_t^2dt<\infty$ for every $T$.

In fact, when $Z$ is a **bounded** random variable and $X$ is a simple process, then above proposition is obvious. Then, approximating $X$ with a simple process, this proposition can be extended to measurable, adapted processes satisfying $[X]_T\triangleq \mathbb{E}\int_0^TX_t^2dt<\infty$.

How should this proposition be extended to $\mathcal{F}_s$-measurable random variable $Z$? Am I right to assume that there should be some constraints on $Z$ (e.g. integrability)?

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2451524/36150

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot and sorry for the duplication.